# Replace the file name in a formula with text from another cell

Tags: excel, reference, filenames

I have a formula in J3 that counts the length of a string in $A$10 from a different file.

=LEN('134-2022-04-08-ZHW.sgf'!$A$10)

I tried to change this to:

=LEN(A3!$A$10)

so that it replaces the file name 134-2022-04-08-ZHW.sgf with a string (a different file name) from cell A3 but it brings up a window and asks me to select the file I want to open.
The result is a #REF! error.

Any help is greatly appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found my answer using indirect.

=LEN(INDIRECT("'"&A3&"'"&"!$A$10"))